# Chatbot is not responding in Flask application on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, chatbot, pythonanywhere

I built a chatbot in python and flask and now i tried to deploy it to pythonanywhere.
You can see it here: http://muellerjustin.pythonanywhere.com/

Unfortunately, the chatbot is not responding when you send messages. I don't know why because on my local server everything works perfectly and the chatbot responds to questions even though it's the same files.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please share the log details provided by pythonanywhere? Thanks!